# Weed out duplicates from a bash array and save to a file

Tags: arrays, bash

I am trying to weed out duplicates from a file. Contents are numbers and names, names could be (e.g. of a duplicate name): ABC ABCxxyy ABC123 ABClmn etc... (so here I only want ABC in my file). To get this, I wrote following code. Currently it uses file read/writes. I want to change this code using arrays, but not able to figure.

Here is the current code:

```
for h in `cat name.list`
do
count=`grep -c $h name.list`
if (( $count >= 1 ))
then
    echo $h >> name.list.new            #building the new list
    grep -v $h name.list > name.list.tmpcopy    #rebuilding the name.list file...
    mv name.list.tmpcopy name.list
fi
done
```

I tried, but I get the same original list as output:

```
while read line
do
    array+=("$line")
done < name.list

#loop thru the array:...
for ((i=0; i < ${#array[*]}; i++))
do
    h=${array[i]}
    match=$(echo "${array[@]:0}" | tr " " "\n" | grep -c $h)
    if (( $match >= 1 ))
    then
        # remove all matched names from array..... Longest match from front of string(s)
        array=${array[@]##$h}

        #save the current name to new array
        array3[${#array3[*]}]=$h
    fi
done

for ELEMENT in "${array3[@]}"
do
 echo $ELEMENT
done > name.list.new
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
declare -a names=( $(<name.list) )

len=${#names[@]}

for i in $(seq 0 $len); do
  if [ "${names[$i]}" != "" ]; then
    m=${names[$i]}
    for j in $(seq 0 $len); do
      if [ $i -ne $j ]; then
        if [ "$m" == "${names[$j]:0:${#m}}" ]; then
          unset names[$j]
        fi
      fi
    done
  fi
done

for name in "${names[@]}"; do
  echo $name
done > name.list.new
```

**Step-by-step:**

The code first declares an array

```
declare -a names=( ... )
```

and reads the content of `name.list` into it:

```
$(<name.list)
```

Then it iterates over all indexes of the array:

```
for i in $(seq 0 $len); do
  ...
done
```

As a safety guard empty fields are skipped over:

```
  if [ "${names[$i]}" != "" ]; then
    ...
  fi
```

Non-empty fields are read into the variable `$m` (for convenience)

```
    m=${names[$i]}
```

Then an inner loop iterates over all indexes of the array except the index currently processed in the outer loop (`$i`):

```
    for j in $(seq 0 $len); do
      if [ $i -ne $j ]; then
        ...
      fi
    done
```

If the first *length-of-`$m`* characters of the field at index `$j` are the same as `$m` that field is removed:

```
        if [ "$m" == "${names[$j]:0:${#m}}" ]; then
          unset names[$j]
        fi
```

Finally the remaining values are written to the output file:

```
for name in "${names[@]}"; do
  echo $name
done > name.list.new
```

Comment: thank you. works perfectly, can you kindly explain step by step? so that I may use the learning in future solutions? thx again!